# Calculate average values in a nested dict of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has the following structure;

```
d = {'actor1': {'salary': {'year1': 60, 'year2': 65}, 'age': 30},
     'actor2': {'salary': {'year1': 20, 'year2': 30}, 'age': 17},
     'actor3': {'salary': {'year1': 50, 'year2': 80}, 'age': 25}}
```

I want the output to be as follows;

```
b = {'average': {'salary': {'year1': 43.3, 'year2': 58.3}, 'age': 24}}
```

So the inner dict can contain values which are both numbers, or dictionaries. If it is a dictionary we are guaranteed to have the same keys for each constituent dictionary (ie : the same `years` will always appear in `salary` for each `actor`).

I don't have a problem finding the correct value for the `age` key, which can be done as follows;

```
actor_keys = list(d)
b = {}
b['average'] = {}
b['average']['age'] = np.mean([b[i]['age'] for i in actor_keys])
```

Is there a nice similar kind of calculation that aggregates over the keys inside `salary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion for a more robust solution to handle input of an unknown depth:

```
from itertools import groupby
data = {'actor1': {'salary': {'year1': 60, 'year2': 65}, 'age': 30}, 'actor2': {'salary': {'year1': 20, 'year2': 30}, 'age': 17}, 'actor3': {'salary': {'year1': 50, 'year2': 80}, 'age': 25}}
def ave(d):
  _data = sorted([i for b in d for i in b.items()], key=lambda x:x[0])
  _d = [(a, [j for _, j in b]) for a, b in groupby(_data, key=lambda x:x[0])]
  return {a:ave(b) if isinstance(b[0], dict) else round(sum(b)/float(len(b)), 1) for a, b in _d}

result = {'average':ave(list(data.values()))}
```

Output:

```
{'average': {'age': 24.0, 'salary': {'year1': 43.3, 'year2': 58.3}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another recursive solution:

```
def average_dicts(dicts):
    result = {}
    for i, d in enumerate(dicts):
        for k, v in d.items():
            update_dict_average(result, k, v, i)
    return result

def update_dict_average(current, key, update, n):
    if isinstance(update, dict):
        subcurrent = current.setdefault(key, {})
        for subkey, subupdate in update.items():
            update_dict_average(subcurrent, subkey, subupdate, n)
    else:
        current[key] = (current.get(key, 0) * n + update) / (n + 1)

d = {'actor1': {'salary': {'year1': 60, 'year2': 65}, 'age': 30},
     'actor2': {'salary': {'year1': 20, 'year2': 30}, 'age': 17},
     'actor3': {'salary': {'year1': 50, 'year2': 80}, 'age': 25}}

result = {'average': average_dicts(d.values())}
print(result)
# {'average': {'salary': {'year1': 43.333333333333336, 'year2': 58.333333333333336}, 'age': 24.0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

```
def avg(nums):
    nums = list(nums)
    return round(sum(nums) / len(nums), 1)

d = {'actor1': {'salary': {'year1': 60, 'year2': 65}, 'age': 30},
     'actor2': {'salary': {'year1': 20, 'year2': 30}, 'age': 17},
     'actor3': {'salary': {'year1': 50, 'year2': 80}, 'age': 25}}

average = {'salary': {}}
average['age'] = avg(actor['age'] for actor in d.values())
for year in list(d.values())[0]['salary']:
    average['salary'][year] = avg(actor['salary'][year] for actor in d.values())

b = {'average': average}
```

```
>>> print(b)
{'average': {'salary': {'year1': 43.3, 'year2': 58.3}, 'age': 24.0}}
```

This can handle an arbitrary positive number of years and actors, and doesn't require `itertools` or `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

Functional approach:

```
import itertools
from statistics import mean

d = {'actor1': {'salary': {'year1': 60, 'year2': 65}, 'age': 30},
     'actor2': {'salary': {'year1': 20, 'year2': 30}, 'age': 17},
     'actor3': {'salary': {'year1': 50, 'year2': 80}, 'age': 25}}

#helpers
age = operator.itemgetter('age')
salary = operator.itemgetter('salary')
year = operator.itemgetter(0)
value = operator.itemgetter(1)

ages = map(age,d.values())
avg_age = mean(ages)
print(f'avg_age: {avg_age}')

salaries = map(dict.items, map(salary, d.values()))
salaries = sorted(itertools.chain.from_iterable(salaries), key=year)
for key, group in itertools.groupby(salaries, year):
    avg = mean(map(value, group))
    print(f'avg for {key}: {avg}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution reusing what you did for age :

```py
b = {}
b['average'] = {}
b['average']["salary"] = {"year1":np.mean([d.get(i).get('salary').get('year1') for i in d]),"year2":np.mean([d.get(i).get('salary').get('year2') for i in d])}
```